# dealing with stdafx.h when have separate directory library

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have library that consist of many directories each of them contains `libX.cpp` and `libX.h` files where `X` is directory name. One `libX` might be used in different projects. Problem is that while compiling each project asks include `stdafx.h` in `libX.cpp`. I suppose I must include `stdafx.h` file that was generated for current project (correct me if I'm wrong). Ok, I'm writing `#include "some_absolute_path1\stdafx.h"` in for example `libA.cpp` file. 
But I'm using the same libA.cpp in another project and then I must change line

```
#include "some_absolute_path1\stdafx.h"
```

to

```
#include "some_absolute_path2\stdafx.h"
```

It is not very comfortable to change stdafx.h path while switching between projects.

What is best way to deal in that situation?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply not use stdafx.h. It is only used for precompiled headers.

You can do `#include "some_absolute_path2\libX.h"`

If you still want to use precompiled headers you just `#include "some_absolute_path2\libX.h"` in the stdafx.h of the project that needs the library.

Comment: `You can simply not use stdafx.h. It is only used for precompiled headers.` I can't - visual studio reports error if I will not use it. `You can do #include "some_absolute_path2\libX.h"` you mean I can include libX.h to stdafx.h? I thought stdafx.h must be included in to libX.h .

Answer (score 0):

Any include is required when your lib is using some of the resources defined in that file to be included. If you need to include stdafx.h is because you have some dependency that is forcing that. You should review what causes you to require this project related file to be included in your libraries (not specific of the project)

I found this article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precompiled_header

I then would try to move stdafx.h to be the first include in your main.cpp where you also include your libx.h files.

Comment: I have done simple libX.cpp with only one line 
`int  n(int f){ return 0;}` But compiler throws me error `Error 1 error C1010: unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. Did you forget to add '#include "StdAfx.h"' to your source? c:\A\LibA.cpp` What in this line causes to use precompiled headers?

Comment: then why do you need to add the include line for stdafx.h? do you get any error or warning?

Comment: yes, I got error: Error 1 error C1010: unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. Did you forget to add '#include "StdAfx.h"' to your source? c:\A\LibA.cpp